# Can't run docker container on Marathon with network HOST?

Tags: cassandra, network-programming, docker, mesos, marathon

I am trying to run some cassandra instances (docker containers) on marathon.

This following description works well:

```
{
    "id": "cassandra",
    "constraints": [["hostname", "CLUSTER", "docker-sl-vm"]],
    "container": {
        "type": "DOCKER",
        "docker": {
            "image": "cassandra:latest",
            "network": "BRIDGE",
            "portMappings": [ {"containerPort": 9042,"hostPort": 0,"servicePort": 9042,"protocol": "tcp"} ]
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "CASSANDRA_SEED_COUNT": "1"
    },
    "cpus": 0.5,
    "mem": 512.0,
    "instances": 1,
    "backoffSeconds": 1,
    "backoffFactor": 1.15,
    "maxLaunchDelaySeconds": 3600
}
```

However, I was following a [tutorial](http://3h4x.github.io/cassandra/marathon/docker/mesos/2015/03/28/cassandra-on-marathon.html) that uses the following description:

```
{
    "id": "cassandra-seed",
    "constraints": [
        [
            "hostname",
            "UNIQUE"
        ]
    ],
    "ports": [
        7199,
        7000,
        7001,
        9160,
        9042
    ],
    "requirePorts": true,
    "container": {
        "type": "DOCKER",
        "docker": {
            "image": "cassandra:latest",
            "network": "HOST",
            "privileged": true
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "CASSANDRA_SEED_COUNT": "1"
    },
    "cpus": 0.5,
    "mem": 512,
    "instances": 2,
    "backoffSeconds": 1,
    "backoffFactor": 1.15,
    "maxLaunchDelaySeconds": 3600,
    "healthChecks": [
        {
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "gracePeriodSeconds": 30,
            "intervalSeconds": 30,
            "portIndex": 4,
            "timeoutSeconds": 60,
            "maxConsecutiveFailures": 30
        }
    ],
    "upgradeStrategy": {
        "minimumHealthCapacity": 0.5,
        "maximumOverCapacity": 0.2
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

If I try ot use the second Marathon description, It takes forever and never loads. It just gets stuck on deploying and do not give me any error at the DEBUG section.

PS.: I am running the mesos cluster into a VirtualBox Ubuntu trusty Guest.

**UPDATE ========================================**

I've erased the logs and tried to run it again. The log result is shown below:
Content of [mesos-slave.docker-sl-vm.invalid-user.log.INFO.20151110-130520.2713](http://pastebin.com/XbAjyZ2S)

Comment: Could you show related log in master-slave?

Comment: mesos-slave you mean? getting it!

Comment: As already said in your other question, running via `HOST` networking is useless if you want to run two instances on the same Mesos Slave, because the ports are then blocked.

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33651860/1603357